# How do you make a scrollview scroll using the swipe gesture but not with the drag gesture?

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview

I am trying to build a UIScrollView that you can navigate around by swiping but not by dragging. I want to instead for the drag gesture to be used for selecting areas of the scrollview.

So far I have implemented the drag gesture for selecting the area but not done the harder bit of changing the scrollview so the dragging gesture is not enabled.

I have a view which is a subview of the scrollview that contains the area selection code:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(TOUCH_BEGAN, object: touches)
}
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(TOUCH_MOVED, object: touches)
}
override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(TOUCH_ENDED, object: touches)
}
```

The notifications just get detected in the viewcontroller and select the area I want (the app is basically a wordsearch so the touch just selects the letters the user wants to select).

I'm unsure whether what I'm trying to do is actually possible and have looked around so much but haven't found any answers so far. I think the way to do it is by stopping the userinteraction of the scrollview and then manually program it by just detecting swipe gestures. But again I think that is very difficult and having tried it outside my limited swift knowledge.